# Looking for a Django nag system

Tags: python, django

I have a Django app. I've implemented a few "nag" boxes in a rather manual way, and I'm now looking for a dedicated module/framework for such nags.

**What do I mean by "nag"?** Those are little boxes that show up near the top of each page on the site, similar to Django's built-in `messages`, that tell the user of something that requires his attention. For example, if a user's credit card is about to expire, we need to show a nag saying "Your credit card is about to expire, click here to enter a new one". If a recent credit card charge failed, we need to show a nag. If he hasn't verified his email address, we need to show a nag.

Why not use the built-in `messages` framework? Because these nags are a bit different than messages. Messages are shown one time, and then they're cleared, while nags should show every time on every page on the website that the user visits. Nags should have a "close" button which will actually function as a "snooze" button, causing the message not to be shown for a specified time period, like 24 hours.

Did anyone implement something like this? A framework in which I can create these nags, specify their conditions for appearing, their snooze abilities, and possibly more features?

Comment: Sounds like the orange bar here on SO.

Comment: Have you considered using jQuery?

Comment: Ironically, if you *did* want to know how to do it yourself, your question would be valid, but since you're just asking for recommendations of existing code, it's not: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: @ChrisPratt: He's not asking "What is your favorite X?", he's asking "Is there a framework that does X?".

Comment: And the difference is? He's still using StackOverflow as a Google surrogate. And, that's not the point of this site.

Comment: Well, I guess a google search came up empty, as this request is difficult to define. This is where it's helpful to ask real people. I don't see how this question is off topic.

Comment: The Django message could be shown [as many times as you want](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/messages/#expiration-of-messages) actually

Comment: @okm: That's not sufficient, because that works for all messages instead of a few select messages only. Also, no snooze feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it client-side by adding those nagging message in the cookies and showing them on every page load. with a close function handler that would remove the cookie.

Comment: That's an idea for how to implement this feature. I appreciate the suggestion but I'm looking for a ready implementation.

Comment: What about switching browsers?

Comment: Django Message could achieve this, no need to reinvent it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this in realtime - in other words, the user doesn't have to refresh to get your nag box - use a combination of signals + [ajax push engine (ape)](http://www.ape-project.org/wiki/index.php/Main)  and add [jquery](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/a-jquery-ui-growl-ubuntu-notification-widget/) for the actual widget.

Josh Wright did a [write up](http://www.alittletothewright.com/index.php/2010/01/apedjango-and-signals/) on how to wire all this together.

Comment: No need for realtime and all the required complexities. Thanks.